# How to create IMACROS dropdown menu scraping code?

Tags: imacros

I have problem creating dropdown menu size scraping code, Could you help me please ?

http://www.matchesfashion.com/intl/prod ... oat-156738

12 UK- should out
14 UK
16 UK

I would like to get the data like " 12 UK- should out ; 14 UK ; 16 UK " in an excel cell.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write your code. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

`'TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:size-chooser EXTRACT=HTM
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:size-chooser EXTRACT=TXTALL
SET TRIM EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/^\\s*|\\s*$/g, \"\");")
SET delimiter ","
SET replaced EVAL("'{{TRIM}}'.replace(/\\n+/g, '{{delimiter}}');")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
ADD !EXTRACT {{replaced}}`

here is the code

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
' ...
SET replaced EVAL("'{{TRIM}}'.replace(/(\\d+)/g, '; $1').replace(';', '') + ' ';")
' ...
```